# Hibernate Search returns outdated data

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-search

I am using a JPARepository to create and update my entities.
Both via the save() method.
Searching with Hibernate Search works fine when I create an entity, but when I update it weird things start to happen.

The update gets recognized in the sense, that only the updated data that actually matches the search gets found but it still returns the entity containing the old data. Using JPAs findAll returns the updated version of the entity.

An example:
Apple gets updated via save() to now be banana.
I can now search banana via a hibernate search query and it finds an entity with the name apple.

After restarting the server the problem is resolved.

What could be my problem here ?

Edit some code for clarification:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@AnalyzerDef(name = "edgeNgram",
    tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = WhitespaceTokenizerFactory.class),
    filters = {
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class), // Replace accented characeters by their simpler counterpart (è => e, etc.)
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class), // Lowercase all characters
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = EdgeNGramFilterFactory.class,
            params = {
                @Parameter(name = "minGramSize", value = "1"),
                @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "10")
            }
        ) // Generate prefix tokens)
    })
@AnalyzerDef(name = "edgeNGram_query",
    tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = WhitespaceTokenizerFactory.class),
    filters = {
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class), // Replace accented characeters by their simpler counterpart (è => e, etc.)
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class) // Lowercase all characters
    })
public class Customer {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Size(max = 100)
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Field(analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "edgeNgram"))
    private String firstName;
//more class
}
```

The Hibernate search

```
    @Transactional
    public List<Customer> searchCustomerByFirstAndLastNamePhrase(String text){

    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

    Query query = fullTextEntityManager
        .getSearchFactory()
        .buildQueryBuilder()
        .forEntity(Customer.class)
        .overridesForField("firstName", "edgeNGram_query")
        .overridesForField("lastName","edgeNGram_query")
        .get()
        .simpleQueryString()
        .onFields("firstName","lastName")
        .withAndAsDefaultOperator()
        .matching(text)
        .createQuery();

    List<Customer> results = getJpaQuery(query).getResultList();

    return results;
    }

    //step 1
private QueryBuilder getQueryBuilder() {

    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

    return fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
        .buildQueryBuilder()
        .forEntity(Customer.class)
        .get();
}

//step 3
private FullTextQuery getJpaQuery(org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery) {

    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

    return fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Customer.class);
}

public void initSearchIndex() {
    entityManager = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager
        = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
    try {
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the JPARep

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {}
```

Comment: This sounds like a caching issue. Is 2nd level cache enabled for the searched entity? It looks as though the query results were being materialized using the cached values

Comment: how would i check this ?
Cached annotations are not set in the entity class

Comment: Have you enabled 2nd level caching (by setting `hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache` in Hibernate properties, or `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache` in Spring Boot properties to `true`)? If so, try disabling it and rerunning the test. If not, then it's some other issue altogether

Comment: its not set set at all so i assume it defaults to false.

Comment: Would you like to check save entity sucessfully ?
Entity a = aRepository.save(a)

Comment: I don't think I understand your question entirely. The entity is updated in the db via the JPARep and save returns the updated entity.

Comment: Did you commit your changes? The index is updated only after the transaction is committed - since it's a different system you need to consider when changes which you are planning to do on your database are actually being applied to the index.

Comment: I assumed updates ect. would update the index automatically. How would I commit updates so the index is updated for the entity

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by not not creating an entity manager by myself like down below.

```
entityManager = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
```

I instead use the entity manager, which is autowired.
This one is not fully created in the constructor and thus initSearchIndex() throws an error. Waiting until the first search request arrives and then calling initSearchIndex() once works perfect.